# Yii2 validator match pattern

Tags: validation, yii2, pattern-matching

My validator does not work. I'm truing to get it to receive just positive numbers with possible 2 digits after a point. This does not work though the pattern look ok (this should not be the pattern but if you think that there is a better one plase attach)

```
[['money'], 'match', 'pattern' => '^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$']
```

Comment: Does it work with regex delimiters? `'pattern' => '/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/'`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need  an array of fields so try  and regex delimiter

```
['money', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/']
```